# Computer clock as pseudo-random generator

Tags: c, random, generator

Most modern computers exhibit non deterministic behavior, what makes impossible to tell how many clock cycles will occur between two consecutive calls to read the computer clock.

The following code is a pseudo random number generator for one byte using the computer clock.

```
unsigned long occurrences = 0;
unsigned long total = 0;

while (true) {
    if ((clock() & 0xFF) == 60) // testing ocurrences for a given number, 60 for instance
        occurrences++;
    total++;
    printf("%f\n", (float)occurrences / (float)total ); // this should be approximately 1/256 = 0.00390625
}
```

Excluding serious applications like encription for instance, it could be used in mobile platforms for games.

I wonder what could be the advantages and disadvantages of such implementation.

Comment: Making your own 'random' number generator: A really, really bad idea...This is quite possibly the worst example...

Comment: In what way does `clock()` give you anything random at all?  Your "splitting" code is pretty fragile (read: wrong), too.

Comment: And once you get "splitting" working, you can apply it to any number at all, pseudo-random or truly random timestamp or from any other source really. Altogether, no part of this question makes any sense.

Comment: @CarlNorum clock() is not completely random, but in my app is very difficult to predict when it will be called

Comment: It's not random at all!  It's for sure monotonically increasing if nothing else.

Comment: @delnan rand() input is integer, by splitting it the result has much less resolution

Comment: You either want a random value or .. you want the "time". Pick the correct function and use it. *There is no question here.* (Do note the various seeding/implementation issues with `rand`, however! A predictable seed is really no better - and could be worse than - `clock()`.)

Comment: @CarlNorum AFAIK there is no such thing as a real random generator inside the PC, those things are very expensive, like the ones used in online casinos

Comment: There's so much wrong with that I don't even know where to start. `rand` is not the only PRNG. You can trivially call it twice to achieve the same effect. `int` may - for example on 32 bit systems - have the same size as the return type of `clock` (which returns `clock_t`, not `unsigned long`). As for real randomness: Yes, you need special hardware for that, but that doesn't mean PRNGs are pointless!

Comment: Just my two cents, this [Article](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) is a good read on random numbers and may help your concept on them.

Comment: @SchautDollar Very useful reading, one concern: is it seeding the rand function with the machine clock different from using the clock itself, even when the clock is read with no predictable pattern

Comment: @rraallvv Some backing data would probably help your argument. You are really looking for something that can produce an equal distribution of values with any seed for a more pure way of truly getting a random value. If your method has a better distribution then other proven methods, then you have won your argument, if you have brought to the community a way of achieving a low quality way of getting a random value, then your solution is flawed.  EITHER WAY though, you are helping the community by providing a solution that could help explain why something is the way it is.

Comment: @rraallvv, you are mistaken, almost all PC nowadays have real random generators hidden somewhere. They are not very fast, but are quite sufficient to seed a PRG for example. The question is whether or not your OS gives access to them. On Linux, e.g, with a modern kernel and configured correctly the system can use real random bits from the TPM chip that you can access through `/dev/random`. As for PRG (and your attitude) this has a loooooooong history, you shouldn't think that you will be capable of implementing a rounder wheel than many high profile scientists did before you.

Comment: @rraalvv: "even when the clock is read with no predictable pattern". How are you going to do that? When called in a loop, there will be a pattern anyway: it's a monotonously increasing sequence of numbers, which is not true for `rand()`.

Comment: @JensGustedt There is a [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20020165888?printsec=abstract#v=onepage&q&f=false) that proposes to use the randomness of the trascienstate state in a PC clock to seed a random generator, wich would be a very good improvement. But by now regular commercial PCs lack of good random generator. For "serious" applications are things like [this](http://www.idquantique.com/random-number-generators/resources/software/97.html), but they are very expensive.

Comment: @SchautDollar I would like to find some proof of the randomness of the clock as a random generator, but it would need some time and investigation. The basis is the characteristic that have all PCs where they works in a not deterministic way, which makes imposible to determine for instace how many clock cycles have passed since the last time the random generator was called.

Comment: @Evert Please see my comment above

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? I have linux on a PC, it uses TPM and has a quite satisfactory random generator. Your only question in your "question" was "Am I missing something?". From my POV, the answer was "yes, a lot". There are tons of literature on random generators and pseudo random generators, and probably even on the relationship to the clock. SO is not the place to discuss, but to ask concrete technical questions.

Comment: @JensGustedt TPM [seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module#Criticism) not an obvious solution for most applications. What do you mean by "concrete technical questions", please see this [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books), most of them seem very subjective to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the proper way to use `rand()` or, more specifically, `srand()`.

You need to call `srand()` exactly once during program run.
Do not call `srand()` in a loop.
Do not call `srand()` before each call to `rand()`.
The best way to ensure proper `srand()` management is to call it once inside your `main()` function and then forget about it: just use `rand()` afterwards.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* rand, srand */
#include <time.h>   /* time */

int main(void) {
    /* initialization */
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* input, possibly calling rand() */

    /* process, possibly calling rand() */

    /* output, possibly calling rand() */

    /* termination */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do the "splitting" using a union instead of pointers like that.

And i agree that random numbers and clock are two completely different things, and you made more of a statement than asking a question.

Comment: The union was very useful thanks. The question looks more like a statement, but I'm sure there is room for valid arguments in favor of using the clock as a random generator in some particular cases, which allow answers with a holistic aproach.

Comment: A good random generator in the interval [x,y] will give you the same probability that every number in the interval is extracted, at each call, and statistically the numbers should appear more or less the same number of times.
A clock always increases, you have none of that. And a clock is by definition predictable, so not random.

Comment: I've updated my question with an example

Comment: Yes it gives a good distribution of results but it's not random in the sense that an attacker could trivially predict the results, and usually be able to generate the same random key as you and hence intercept everything. If you are not using randomness for encryption then a not so good random algorithm might do the job as well...